# Do you have to manually include ApplicationHelper in ApplicationController in Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Controller:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def index
    bar_method
```

ApplicationHelper:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def bar_method
```

Viewing the index page raises `undefined method bar_method`.

Does `ApplicationHelper` need to be manually included?

Rails 6.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to include helper module. With `helpers` (in rails 5+), you can access the helper methods. Try this:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def index
    helpers.bar_method
```

Comment: Bleh. So you have to manually include it or manually call it? I wonder why it is not included automatically...

Comment: @BSeven If you want to access the ApplicationHelper methods, you need to use `helpers`.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out this was an update to Rails before 6.

> In previous versions of Rails the controller will include a helper which matches the name of the controller, e.g., MyController will automatically include MyHelper. To return old behavior set config.action_controller.include_all_helpers to false.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html