# How to access ApplicationHelper methods in namespaced views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-on-rails-5.2, ruby-on-rails-6.1, zeitwerk

I have a module ApplicationHelper in app/helpers/application_helper.rb
defined like this

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def some_method(arg)
    
  end
end
```

and i have my view file is here

```
app/views/v1/admin/messages/show.json.jbuilder
```

So i am trying to access the

> some_method()

in view file but it doesn't reflect!
Is this due to namespacing? or what i am not able to understand.
It would be Great if someone explains the concept.
Thanks in advance!

it says undefined method error
what could be the reason?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘it doesn’t reflect’? Are you getting a method-not-found or other error in the logs?

Comment: Please update with the v1/admin/messages controller. Does it inherit from ApplicationController?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58324760/do-you-have-to-manually-include-applicationhelper-in-applicationcontroller-in-ra?

Comment: @rmlockerd yes i am trying to access it in the views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include your controller code, but we'll assume it ultimately inherits from `ActionController::API` (as it should it if it is an API controller). If so, that is the root of it rather than namespacing, etc. Per the ActionController documentation:

> An API Controller is different from a normal controller in the sense
> that by default it doesn't include a number of features that are
> usually required by browser access only: layouts and templates
> rendering, flash, assets, and so on. This makes the entire controller
> stack thinner, suitable for API applications. It doesn't mean you
> won't have such features if you need them: they're all available for
> you to include in your application, they're just not part of the
> default API controller stack.

One of the side effects of the thinner API controller is that they don't automatically include helpers like a standard Rails controller. You can easily add that back in, though.

**messages_controller.rb**

```rb
class Api::V1::MessagesController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::Helpers 
  helper ApplicationHelper
  
  def show
    # whatever
  end
end
```

**app/helpers/application_helper.rb**

```rb
module MessagesHelper
  def some_method(arg)
    # whatever
  end
end
```

**app/views/messages/show.json.jbuilder**

```json
json.bogus do
  thing1: some_method('banana')
end
```

If you have lots of API controllers, you can of course stick it in a base controller class they all inherit from like so:

```rb
class Api::V1::ApiController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::Helpers
  helper ApplicationHelper
end
```